# How to compress ext4 partition with Acronis while backup?

Tags: backup, compression, ext4, acronis-trueimage

With *Acronis*, when I set to compress ext4 partition before backup, the result is a raw backup and not compressed.

The same process with NTFS or FAT32 partition, results are compressed.

Please tell me how to configure Acronis to really compress ext4 partition while backup. Or, which version of Acronis can really compress ext4 partition in order to backup it.

Comment: What version of Acronis are you using? Please be specific.

Comment: https://kb.acronis.com/content/6045

Comment: I don't ask for ext4 support. I know that it's supported. I Tried with 2013 and 2016 with the disc boot for backup.